# Proper attribution in an SDK

Tags: open-source, licensing

I've a colleague who won't consider using Otto because it's Apache 2 licensed and so requires attribution.

The reason my colleague thinks we can't attribute properly is that we produce an SDK that will be used by others and so can't insist on attribution *in* their app (i.e. a page within the app itself).

I thought a NOTICE file in the SDK was suitable but he thinks not.

[I asked Otto and they didn't feel qualified to say](https://github.com/square/otto/issues/132).

Which of us is correct? Or if we're both wrong is there a correct thing to do? The Apache 2 license isn't uncommon so I thought this would be a simple thing but (and maybe my google-fu is failing) but I found very contradictory answers out there.

Thanks (apologies if this is the wrong place to ask - pointers on the right place to ask appreciated too)

---

Edit, I believed this to be on-topic because https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic refers to "software tools commonly used by programmers". I think licensing is a tool that we use (and that I'd like the community to help me understand).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apache licensing and not about coding. Consider consulting [the Apache license FAQ](http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html).

Comment: OK, I wondered that before I posted but the Apache license is used in software. I've consulted the FAQ. I don't believe they're clear (which might be me not grokking but then that's why I'm here).

Comment: I also didn't know juridic was a word... awesome, thanks @ben75

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra oups... I fix it.

Comment: @ben75 no, no - it is a word. More commonly juridical (which I had seen before) but also juridic is allowed! http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Juridic :D

Comment: This question may be more acceptable on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/  (if not a duplicate)

Comment: Ooh @ben75 thank you - there are hits for A2 on there. I've never used programmers-sx before. I'll have a poke around.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without providing any kind of legal advice, I'd suggest that you may wish to review section 4(d) of the Apache License, Version 2.0.

- http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

In particular,

"... or, within a display generated by the Derivative Works, if and wherever such third-party notices normally appear."

and note that the phrase begins with the word "or".

Please also consider that the people making use of the SDK are the people who are making use of the Derivative Work, and that those are the people who must be aware of the ASF's contribution.

When a vendor uses the HTTP server to publish web sites, there is no expectation that any of the web sites will include attribution to the ASF.